# tfs2010 automatically set build quality

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, build-automation

we use TFS 2010 and have configured our build system to compile test and deploy our projects on a CI policy.

One thing that I would also like to be able to do is automatically set the "Build Quality" at the end of the build process that is either "Released" or Rejected"

I have customised out build template to allow automatic deployment base on where ALL projects compiled and ALL unit tests passed.

I also added what I though would set the build quality but no matter which outcome the quality is never updated. Looking at the build log **it actually is hitting the SetBuildProperties action but that doesn't appear to "save" it**.

I am doing this in the xaml designer in vs2010 if that helps.

Has anyone experienced anything like this when attempting to set a build property while it is still in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it appears that I missed a special box at the top of the properties page that actually determines which properties are to be set:

PropertiesToSet: Quality, ....

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you say `at the top of the properties page`, which properties are you referring to? Can you add a screenshot and more detailed instructions?